# embulk input redshift output bigquery data loss

Tags: java

When I use embulk tools, from the redshift import the Google bigquery, when adding is_skip_job_result_check out attributes: true is that the data is lost!(every data to allow the import of bigquery to have at most 1000 wrong record), it is my config. Yml file.

**in:**

```
type: redshift
  host: ...
  port: 5439
  user: my_user
  password: password
  database: my_database
  schema: public
  fetch_rows: 1000
```

query:

```
SELECT  * FROM app140681.events140681_5747135  
WHERE TO_CHAR(event_time, 'YYYYMMDD') = '20160707'
```

**out:**

```
type: bigquery
  auth_method: json_key  
  json_keyfile:
    content: |
      {
          "private_key_id": "...",
           "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
           "client_email": "..."
      }
  project: my_project
  dataset: testdataset
  auto_create_table: true
  table: test_redshift
  emplate_table: test_redshift_schema.json
  #schema_file: ./schema.json
  max_bad_records: 1000
  abort_on_error: false
  compression: NONE
  is_skip_job_result_check: true
  job_status_polling_interval: 5
  source_format: CSV
  "CSV"
  default_timezone: 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 1):

If `is_skip_job_result_check` is true, embulk-output-bigquery skips waiting BigQuery load job finishes, so embulk-output-bigquery can do nothing anymore. If `is_skip_job_result_check` is false, embulk-output-bigquery can get the result status of the load job, and it retries when it is necessary automatically.

With `is_skip_job_result_check: true`, you have to check whether embulk load job is not aborted on BigQuery console manually, and retry running embulk if necessary. Please check BigQuery console.

Comment: If you mean, you always (not occasionally) lose data with `is_skip_job_result_check: true` although you always succeeds loading into bigquery with `is_skip_job_result_check: false`, it is apparently something wrong with the plugin. Please let me know (I am the author, by the way).

Comment: 1.When set to is_skip_job_result_check: true, I have already checked biqery log, there is no error, but the data will be lost
 ( the data are not copied into the database Occasionally )
I check LOAD_TEMP_ * the data in the table is correct,Should be in the LOAD_TEMP_* to the destination table when copying problems?

Comment: 2.Copy data error is allowed (max_bad_records:1000), and to ensure that the data will not be interrupted (abort_on_error:false
) But when the data is wrong, the program will still be interrupted?
 Just joined (is_skip_job_result_check:true) program in order to work out,
 but each time the correct data will be lost? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: > But when the data is wrong, the program will still be interrupted?

No, embulk should not be aborted. If embulk is aborted, it will show you Java stacktrace. You can easily differentiate.

Comment: >  the data are not copied into the database Occasionally

In my experience, BigQuery is unstable occasionally. I usually have to apply almost infinite retry on production environment. I do not recommend to use is_skip_job_result_check: false except for development purpose.

If you mean you **always** lose some data for the same input data for is_skip_job_result_check: false, please let me know.

Comment: I just have to test again.I confirm when is_skip_job_result_check: true data does have lost!
 (Is_skip_job_result_check: false data correct) my email is wangmin@vuclip.com, you can contact me directly.thank you!

Comment: Clear. It is advised to set `abort_on_error: true` (default), and `max_bad_records: 0` (default) If you want to avoid data loss without noticing.

Comment: According to your suggestion, the test have no questions, thank you instructions!